# Can I use a downloaded APK to view ble commands sent by an app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded an apk from the playstore.  I want to find out what commands the app sends to ble devices in order to accomplish certain tasks.

Can I use android studio and the apk to view those commands in the terminal console or something similar?